# Why the effect of onmouseup never take effect?

Tags: javascript, onmouseup

I find the following information on w3schools regarding with The onmousedown, onmouseup and onclick Events:
The onmousedown, onmouseup, and onclick events are all parts of a mouse-click. First when a mouse-button is clicked, the onmousedown event is triggered, then, when the mouse-button is released, the onmouseup event is triggered, finally, when the mouse-click is completed, the onclick event is triggered.

Later I write the following code to test but the onmouseup event never happens?
It only displays 'clicked' after I released the click, but the "Thank You a lot" never appears. Anyone could please clarify that for me? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div onmousedown="mDown(this)" onmouseup="mUp(this)" onclick = "mClick(this)" style="background-color:#D94A38;width:90px;height:20px;padding:40px;">Click Me</div>

<script>
function mClick(obj)
{
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#ec5ead";
    obj.innerHTML="Clicked"
}
function mDown(obj)
{
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#1ec5e5";
    obj.innerHTML="Release Me"
}

function mUp(obj)
{
    obj.style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
    obj.innerHTML="Thank You a lot"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you're *replacing* the content; the `mouseup` event fires, then the `click` event fires just after it (fast enough for you not to be able to see the effect of the `mouseup` event). What happens if you append to the `innerHTML` property rather than setting a new value?

Comment: As a side note, you may want to consider another reference than w3schools...

Comment: It happens. You just need to click on text

Comment: @Anthony your advise is helpful! many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouseup event *is* firing, it's just that it is immediately followed by the click event, so you don't get a chance to see the thankyou message. If you remove the onclick handler, you'll see the message.

Answer (score 1):

A click on an element is when you both mousedown and and mouseup on the same element. The mouseup event is being triggered, but the last thing that happens is the click event.